# Configuring virtual hosts to use both names and port numbers

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, port, bind

On my local machine I have several named virtual hosts set up in apache, all on port 80.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/site1"
    ServerName http://site1.local
        <Directory "site1" >
                Options +Includes
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>   


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/site2"
    ServerName http://site2.local
        <Directory "site2" >
                Options +Includes
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For testing on mobile devices I need these sites to be reachable via my machine's IP address, in which case the first virtual host declared is the default. I assume I need to set up something with listening on different ports in order to be able to access multiple virtual hosts on the same IP address, but I've tried quite a few variations and can't get it so using the port works remotely but the name still works locally.

How do I set up multiple virtual hosts which are both named and listened to on different ports. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the end.

The trick is to use

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:otherportnumber>
```

This way the server name works (because listening on :80) and the IP address + port number works (because no other named host is listening on that port number)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just specify the IP address in the `<VirtualHost>` tag.  This means you need to have separate IP addresses for each vhost, but if you've got to differentiate by IP address, you'll already have those allocated.

Answer (score 0):

The `ServerName` clause should look like this:

```
ServerName test.example.org
```

The rest of your configuration is fine for multiple virtualhosts on the same IP and port. For different IPs, womble's answer is correct.

Comment: Actually, I thought that was weird too so I looked it up [in the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername).  The scheme and port are optional but allowed in `ServerName`.

Comment: Ah, weird. My setup is like his and it works. Something else wrong maybe? DNS?